# Add a number to variable applescript

Tags: variables, text, numbers, applescript, addition

I have a number written in a text file. Is it possible to add another to the number in the text file then replace the old number with the new one? Heres my code:

```
set theFile to POSIX path of "Users:Tyler:Documents:File.txt"
open for access theFile
set theFileContents to read theFile

set theNewFile to run script theFileContents + 1
tell application "TextEdit"
set eof of theFileContents to 0
write theNewFile to theFileContents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly you just want to have a text file with a string and convert that string to a number then increase the value of the number by 1 write it back to the file as a string and save it boom done right ? let me know if this is what you meant.

```
set docsFolder to path to documents folder

set afile to "" & docsFolder & "File.txt"
open for access file afile with write permission
set oldNum to read file afile
set newString to ((oldNum as number) + 1) as string
set eof file afile to 0
log newString
write newString to file afile starting at eof

close access file afile
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was trying to do and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. I'm curious though, what were you tying to do with run script ?

Comment: @mcgralim I have used run script to make a calculator before.

`set theMath to text returned of (display dialog "Insert math problem here" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button 2)`
run script theMath

Comment: hmmm ok , i just didn't see any reason for it in your post i didn't understand what you were expecting it to do